# og:description tag not being honored when page is Liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have added the og:description meta tag to my web page, the content of the element is a locale-specific description of the page. By viewing the page source, I have verifed that the meta tag includes the locale-specific description. When the end user Likes the page however, the English-language description of the page is posted instead.

I have provided all of the required open graph elements as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/). 
I have run the page through the FB debugger, but did not receive any errors or warnings. It is interesting to note that in the debugger, the og:description is not the locale-specific version either, but the English language version!

Is this a known issue with Open Graph? Has anyone else experienced this, and what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: Can you please post links to the page in question? Also, "locale-specific" for who? You mean that there are different urls for different locales?

Comment: I'm sorry, but due to policy issues, I am not be able to post links to the page in question. In regards to your question about the URL, the URL looks the same to the user regardless of her locale preference. By default, the en_US (English-USA) locale is assumed, but the user has the ability to change it on the site's landing page. The locale choice is stored in a session variable.

Comment: Does the debug tool end up on the same page you're inputting? (i.e no redirects or og:url tags pointing to another URL)

Comment: That is correct, it ends up on the same page that I am inputting. There are no redirects or trickery with the og:url.

Answer (score 0):

There are [12 open bugs containing og:description](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs?search_view=search&&search_statuses%5B0%5D=open&search_texts%5B0%5D=og%3adescription) on the official bug reporting tool.  Maybe start there?

Comment: Thanks for that link, Todd. The only problem is that there doesn;t seem to be any useful information from FB about it, in fact most of the offical responses seem to be of the 'Thanks for the report. We will follow up' variety.

Comment: In that case, I would open a new bug.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the locale to the og:url, eg:

<meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsite.com/myservlet?a_parameter=a_value&another_parameter=another_value&locale=fr_CA"/>

While this has allowed me to get around the issue, the root problem - that the og:description attribute is not being honored - is still open.